# How to make each ListItem go to a different activity

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

Im relatively new to the Android world but I have a quick question.

I have a list on one page that has a potentially unlimited amount of rows which will be populated by a database. These will go to different activities based on their type (like Customers etc.) Is it possible to send the user to a specific activity based on which one they tap?

I have seen some solutions that are based on a switch/case, but this seems to be used if you have a list of finite items, and you know the names of those items beforehand.

So, what I am saying is if I use a switch/case solution, how does the application know which buttons goes to which case? Does this need to be defined in the list itself or something in the database?

I can't provide any code at the moment because it's not that far into development and I am also under NDA about the project!

Comment: A switch would seem a likely solution if you have a defined list of all of the possible types. If you do not, try to make one. There are solutions to this, but they're relatively more complicated than a switch.

Comment: please take look over this........http://stackoverflow.com/a/11096757/804447

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in the `setonitemclicklistener()`. This function is called whenever you click on any of the rows of the list view. The position/row number of the item that you have clicked is also passed on to this function.  
Since you are using Database to Populate your List, you can do this :

```
     setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));

          ListView lv = getListView();
          lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            //SEE THIS FUNCTION

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                  /*
                    "position" is the position/row of the item that you have clicked

                    Query your table. Then move the cursor to "position" and get the 
                    details. THen based on the details call a new activity.

                    */
                    Cursor cur=db.query("your table name",null,null,null,null,null.null);
                    cur.moveToPosition(position); // see the argument int position

                //Extract details from this row,process it and send to the respective activiy                       
  });
```